# "error: unknown type name" after declaration

Tags: c, types, makefile

i'm developing a encoder/decoder program, and I used the asn1c compiler to covert my ASN.1 code to C. When you do that, specific .c and .h files are automatically added such as type declarations as well as encoding and decoding files. When I put all these together I keep getting

```
 /Desktop/asn1c/constr_TYPE.h:97:2: error: unknown type name ‘der_type_encoder_f’
```

however inside one of these files they type is explicitly defined. below I have posted the main encoding program, the file I believe is causing the problem, as well as my Makefile.

this is the main program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "/Desktop/asn1c/BACnet-SimpleACK-PDU.h"
#include "/Desktop/asn1c/asn_application.h"
#include "/Desktop/asn1c/constr_TYPE.h"
#include "/Desktop/asn1c/der_encoder.h"



    static int write_out(const void *buffer, size_t size, void *app_key){
            FILE *out_fp = app_key;
            size_t wrote = fwrite(buffer, 1, size, out_fp);
            return (wrote == size) ? 0 : -1;
            }

    int main(int ac, char **av){
            BACnet_SimpleACK_PDU_t *bacnet_simpleack_pdu;
            asn_enc_rval_t ec;

    bacnet_simpleack_pdu = calloc(1, sizeof(BACnet_SimpleACK_PDU_t));



  bacnet_simpleack_pdu -> pdu_type = 15;
  bacnet_simpleack_pdu -> reserved = 0;
  bacnet_simpleack_pdu -> invokeID = 45;
  bacnet_simpleack_pdu -> service_ACK_choice = 0;

  const char *filename = av[1];
  FILE *fp;
  fp  = fopen(filename, "wb");

  ec = der_encode(&asn_DEF_BACnet_SimpleACK_PDU, bacnet_simpleack_pdu, write_out, fp);
  fclose(fp);
  }
```

The Next file below is the one causing the problem

```
 #ifndef _CONSTR_TYPE_H_
 #define _CONSTR_TYPE_H_
 #include "ber_tlv_length.h"
 #include "ber_tlv_tag.h"

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif

 struct asn_TYPE_descriptor_s;   /* Forward declaration */
 struct asn_TYPE_member_s;       /* Forward declaration */

 /*
  * This type provides the context information for various ASN.1 routines,
  * primarily ones doing decoding. A member _asn_ctx of this type must be
  * included into certain target language's structures, such as compound types.
  */
 typedef struct asn_struct_ctx_s {
      short phase;            /* Decoding phase */
      short step;             /* Elementary step of a phase */
      int context;            /* Other context information */
      void *ptr;              /* Decoder-specific stuff (stack elements) */
      ber_tlv_len_t left;     /* Number of bytes left, -1 for indefinite */
 } asn_struct_ctx_t;

 #include "ber_decoder.h"        /* Basic Encoding Rules decoder */
 #include "der_encoder.h"        /* Distinguished Encoding Rules encoder */
 #include "xer_decoder.h"        /* Decoder of XER (XML, text) */
 #include "xer_encoder.h"        /* Encoder into XER (XML, text) */
 #include "per_decoder.h"        /* Packet Encoding Rules decoder */
 #include "per_encoder.h"        /* Packet Encoding Rules encoder */
 #include "constraints.h"        /* Subtype constraints support */

  /*
  * Free the structure according to its specification.
  * If (free_contents_only) is set, the wrapper structure itself (struct_ptr)
  * will not be freed. (It may be useful in case the structure is allocated
  * statically or arranged on the stack, yet its elements are allocated
  * dynamically.)
  */
  typedef void (asn_struct_free_f)(
            struct asn_TYPE_descriptor_s *type_descriptor,
            void *struct_ptr, int free_contents_only);
   #define ASN_STRUCT_FREE(asn_DEF, ptr)   (asn_DEF).free_struct(&(asn_DEF),ptr,0)
   #define ASN_STRUCT_FREE_CONTENTS_ONLY(asn_DEF, ptr)     \
                                    (asn_DEF).free_struct(&(asn_DEF),ptr,1)
    short phase;            /* Decoding phase */
    short step;             /* Elementary step of a phase */
    int context;            /* Other context information */
    void *ptr;              /* Decoder-specific stuff (stack elements) */
    ber_tlv_len_t left;     /* Number of bytes left, -1 for indefinite */
    } asn_struct_ctx_t;

    #include "ber_decoder.h"        /* Basic Encoding Rules decoder */
    #include "der_encoder.h"        /* Distinguished Encoding Rules encoder */
    #include "xer_decoder.h"        /* Decoder of XER (XML, text) */
    #include "xer_encoder.h"        /* Encoder into XER (XML, text) */
    #include "per_decoder.h"        /* Packet Encoding Rules decoder */
    #include "per_encoder.h"        /* Packet Encoding Rules encoder */
    #include "constraints.h"        /* Subtype constraints support */

    /*
     * Free the structure according to its specification.
     * If (free_contents_only) is set, the wrapper structure itself (struct_ptr)
     * will not be freed. (It may be useful in case the structure is allocated
     * statically or arranged on the stack, yet its elements are allocated
     * dynamically.)
     */
     typedef void (asn_struct_free_f)(
            struct asn_TYPE_descriptor_s *type_descriptor,
            void *struct_ptr, int free_contents_only);
    #define ASN_STRUCT_FREE(asn_DEF, ptr)   (asn_DEF).free_struct(&(asn_DEF),ptr,0)
    #define ASN_STRUCT_FREE_CONTENTS_ONLY(asn_DEF, ptr)     \
                                    (asn_DEF).free_struct(&(asn_DEF),ptr,1)

     /*
      * Print the structure according to its specification.
      */
      typedef int (asn_struct_print_f)(
            struct asn_TYPE_descriptor_s *type_descriptor,
            const void *struct_ptr,
            int level,      /* Indentation level */
            asn_app_consume_bytes_f *callback, void *app_key);

     /*
      * Return the outmost tag of the type.
      * If the type is untagged CHOICE, the dynamic operation is performed.
      * NOTE: This function pointer type is only useful internally.
      * Do not use it in your application.
      */
      typedef ber_tlv_tag_t (asn_outmost_tag_f)(
            struct asn_TYPE_descriptor_s *type_descriptor,
            const void *struct_ptr, int tag_mode, ber_tlv_tag_t tag);
      /* The instance of the above function type; used internally. */
      asn_outmost_tag_f asn_TYPE_outmost_tag;

      ^L
      /*
       * The definitive description of the destination language's structure.
       */
       typedef struct asn_TYPE_descriptor_s {
       char *name;     /* A name of the ASN.1 type. "" in some cases. */
       char *xml_tag;  /* Name used in XML tag */
             /*
     * Generalized functions for dealing with the specific type.
     * May be directly invoked by applications.
     */
    asn_struct_free_f  *free_struct;        /* Free the structure */
    asn_struct_print_f *print_struct;       /* Human readable output */
    asn_constr_check_f *check_constraints;  /* Constraints validator */
    ber_type_decoder_f *ber_decoder;        /* Generic BER decoder */
    der_type_encoder_f *der_encoder;        /* Canonical DER encoder */
    xer_type_decoder_f *xer_decoder;        /* Generic XER decoder */
    xer_type_encoder_f *xer_encoder;        /* [Canonical] XER encoder */
    per_type_decoder_f *uper_decoder;       /* Unaligned PER decoder */
    per_type_encoder_f *uper_encoder;       /* Unaligned PER encoder */

    /***********************************************************************
     * Internally useful members. Not to be used by applications directly. *
     **********************************************************************/

    /*
     * Tags that are expected to occur.
     */
    asn_outmost_tag_f  *outmost_tag;        /* <optional, internal> */
    ber_tlv_tag_t *tags;    /* Effective tags sequence for this type */
    int tags_count;         /* Number of tags which are expected */
    ber_tlv_tag_t *all_tags;/* Every tag for BER/containment */
    int all_tags_count;     /* Number of tags */

    asn_per_constraints_t *per_constraints; /* PER compiled constraints */

    /*
      * An ASN.1 production type members (members of SEQUENCE, SET, CHOICE).
     */
    struct asn_TYPE_member_s *elements;
    int elements_count;

    /*
     * Additional information describing the type, used by appropriate
     * functions above.
     */
    void *specifics;
    } asn_TYPE_descriptor_t;

   /*
    * This type describes an element of the constructed type,
    * i.e. SEQUENCE, SET, CHOICE, etc.
    */
    enum asn_TYPE_flags_e {
          ATF_NOFLAGS,
          ATF_POINTER     = 0x01, /* Represented by the pointer */
          ATF_OPEN_TYPE   = 0x02  /* ANY type, without meaningful tag */
     };
     typedef struct asn_TYPE_member_s {
     enum asn_TYPE_flags_e flags;    /* Element's presentation flags */
     int optional;   /* Following optional members, including current */
     int memb_offset;                /* Offset of the element */
     ber_tlv_tag_t tag;              /* Outmost (most immediate) tag */
     int tag_mode;           /* IMPLICIT/no/EXPLICIT tag at current level */
     asn_TYPE_descriptor_t *type;    /* Member type descriptor */
     asn_constr_check_f *memb_constraints;   /* Constraints validator */
     asn_per_constraints_t *per_constraints; /* PER compiled constraints */
           int (*default_value)(int setval, void **sptr);  /* DEFAULT <value> */
    char *name;                     /* ASN.1 identifier of the element */
  } asn_TYPE_member_t;

   /*
    * BER tag to element number mapping.
    */
   typedef struct asn_TYPE_tag2member_s {
        ber_tlv_tag_t el_tag;   /* Outmost tag of the member */
        int el_no;              /* Index of the associated member, base 0 */
        int toff_first;         /* First occurence of the el_tag, relative */
        int toff_last;          /* Last occurence of the el_tag, relatvie */ 
    } asn_TYPE_tag2member_t;

    /*
     * This function is a wrapper around (td)->print_struct, which prints out
     * the contents of the target language's structure (struct_ptr) into the
     * file pointer (stream) in human readable form.
     * RETURN VALUES:
     *       0: The structure is printed.
     *      -1: Problem dumping the structure.
     * (See also xer_fprint() in xer_encoder.h)
     */
       int asn_fprint(FILE *stream,            /* Destination stream descriptor */
       asn_TYPE_descriptor_t *td,      /* ASN.1 type descriptor */
       const void *struct_ptr);        /* Structure to be printed */

      #ifdef __cplusplus
      }

     #endif
```

Here is the Makefile

```
  ecoder_test: ecoder_test.c /Desktop/asn1c/BACnet-SimpleACK-PDU.h     /Desktop/asn1c/OSUINT.h /Desktop/asn1c/BACnetConfirmedServiceChoice.h /Desktop/asn1c/constr_SEQUENCE.h /Desktop/asn1c/constr_TYPE.h /Desktop/asn1c/asn_application.h /Desktop/asn1c/der_encoder.h /Desktop/asn1c/ber_tlv_length.h
    gcc ecoder_test.c /Desktop/asn1c/BACnet-SimpleACK-PDU.h /Desktop/asn1c/OSUINT.h /Desktop/asn1c/BACnetConfirmedServiceChoice.h /Desktop/asn1c/constr_SEQUENCE.h /Desktop/asn1c/constr_TYPE.h /Desktop/asn1c/asn_application.h  /Desktop/asn1c/der_encoder.h /Desktop/asn1c/ber_tlv_length.h  -o ecoder_test
```

The issue is on compile, it is not recognizing der_type_encoder_f which is being declared in der_encoder.h, (I've only included the declaration of that file)

```
    typedef asn_enc_rval_t (der_type_encoder_f) (
            struct asn_TYPE_descriptor_s *type_descriptor,
            void *struct_ptr,       /* Structure to be encoded */
            int tag_mode,           /* {-1,0,1}: IMPLICIT, no, EXPLICIT */
            ber_tlv_tag_t tag,
            asn_app_consume_bytes_f *consume_bytes_cb,      /* Callback */
            void *app_key           /* Arbitrary callback argument */
    );
```

My questions are,

1) does the order of files in the Makefile make a difference, such that on compile, it wont recognize  the type? and if so, why?

2) Can the order things are included in the main program cause the same problem?

Comment: Inclusion order matters, yes. Definitions need to appear before usage. You also don't generally include `.h` files on compilation lines like that as they don't go into the built object. Try removing those and seeing what happens.

Comment: I have tried that, I get the same error,

Comment: What does `ecoder_test.c` contain? What about `asn1c/constr_TYPE.h`?

Comment: ecoder_test.c is the main program, its attached above. asn1c/constr_TYPE.h defines structures that are implemented in der_encoder.h. That is also included above

Comment: The order of prerequisites for the target doesn't matter in that sense (it does, to an extent, control the order in which make processes them though) but like I said since they don't belong on the compilation line it doesn't really matter the order in the prerequisite list.

Comment: `typedef asn_enc_rval_t (der_type_encoder_f)` should be `typedef asn_enc_rval_t (*der_type_encoder_f)` IMO.

Comment: I tried that, and to no avail

Comment: @user3681077 did you ever end up finding a fix? I'm hitting the same issue now with asn1c